# Xcode 4.2 is missing a .xib file?

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I'm pretty new to programming, so I downloaded Xcode 4.2 and got to work. I watched many online tutorials and the main problem I was having was that all the tutorials were for Xcode 4 and not 4.2, meaning when you chose empty application setting, it was missing the .xib file. So I found a tutorial on how to create a .xib file. I got through it all except for one step, and that was to drag the from the window outlet of the xAppdelegate to the window. I've tried this over and over, but it doesn't work.

Here is the tutorial if anyone needs to see it http://www.trappers.tk/site/2011/06/16/mainwindow-xib/

Please someone help me!

Comment: use this link http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/where-is-mainwindow-xib-in-xcode-4-2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging, else it will not work.

[Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/EstablishingBindingsDragging.html).

Comment: But the problem is, the window outlet isn't there at all. When I look under my outlets all I see is something that says rootViewController.

Answer (score 1):

As you Control-drag from an object to your source code, Interface Builder indicates where a new binding is valid. After you’ve made the connection, Xcode displays a dialog you use to configure the binding. You can use the dialog to configure all aspects of the binding.

Interface Builder uses the Xcode index to determine which key paths are valid, and can also discover what controller it should connect through—you can therefore connect from a user interface element such as a table column to a property in a model class header.

Check out the video [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/EstablishingBindingsDragging.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should choose a `SingleViewBased Application` instead of `Empty Application` then study all files that how they connect with each other. You can choose `Master Application` also. They will help you.

see this **Hello world Tutorial** [click me](http://devinsblog.com/2009/01/23/iphone-coding-tutorial-hello-world/).

And **Youtube** is the best way to learning for beginners. Search tutorial video because action teach more than the text.